# Build falhando em projeto PHP no Travis-CI

Tags: php, composer, travis-ci, docker

Estou tentando fazer builds noturnas de um projeto em PHP no [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/) mas estou apanhando. Minhas builds estão falhando porque o Travis-CI diz não encontrar o composer. Há mais detalhes no log abaixo.

```
Using worker: worker-linux-docker-c22a70ed.prod.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-3

Build system information
Build language: ruby
Build image provisioning date and time
Thu Feb  5 15:09:33 UTC 2015
Operating System Details
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Linux Version
3.13.0-29-generic
Cookbooks Version
a68419e https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/a68419e
GCC version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

LLVM version
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Pre-installed Ruby versions
ruby-1.9.3-p551
Pre-installed Node.js versions
v0.10.36
Pre-installed Go versions
1.4.1
Redis version
redis-server 2.8.19
riak version
2.0.2
MongoDB version
MongoDB 2.4.12
CouchDB version
couchdb 1.6.1
Neo4j version
1.9.4
RabbitMQ Version
3.4.3
ElasticSearch version
1.4.0
Installed Sphinx versions
2.0.10
2.1.9
2.2.6
Default Sphinx version
2.2.6
Installed Firefox version
firefox 31.0esr
PhantomJS version
1.9.8
ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:23+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_76, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/rgiaviti/laravel-correios-track.git rgiaviti/laravel-correios-track
Cloning into 'rgiaviti/laravel-correios-track'...
remote: Counting objects: 69, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (40/40), done.
remote: Total 69 (delta 14), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 20
Receiving objects: 100% (69/69), 11.17 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (14/14), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd rgiaviti/laravel-correios-track
$ git checkout -qf e2c8293aa5a996f5d8bbdef6788e4e2d84c15c1e

This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.
If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml
See http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.
$ rvm use default
Using /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13 revision 48407) [x86_64-linux]
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.26.10 (latest-minor) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.7.6
$ gem --version
2.4.5
$ composer self-update
/home/travis/build.sh: line 41: composer: command not found

The command "composer self-update" failed and exited with 127 during .

Your build has been stopped.
```

O que eu percebi é que o Travis-CI **está setando o ambiente para Ruby ao invés do ambiente em PHP**. Mesmo eu configurando o arquivo `.travis.yml` para usar o ambiente PHP, parece o que na hora da build, o Travis-CI ignora minha configurações. Abaixo está o meu arquivo **.travis.yml**.

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.4
  - 5.5
  - 5.6
  - hhvm
  - hhvm-nightly

before_script:
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction --dev
```

Já vasculhei toda a documentação do Travis-CI e postei essa [mesma questão no Stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308823/building-failing-at-travis-ci-due-to-composer-command-call). Ainda não achei solução. Também configurei o Travis-CI para somente fazer a build caso o .travis.yml estivesse presente e ele faz o build. Sendo assim creio que o Travis-CI está lendo o .travis.yml.

Outro ponto é que verifiquei em outros projetos para ver como deve ser o arquivo .travis.yml e aperentemente está tudo correto.

Não faço idéia se o problema está no próprio Travis-CI ou no meu arquivo ou alguma configuração que eu não verifiquei.

Answer (score 1):

Entrei em contato com o suporte do Travis-CI explicando meu problema. Eles checaram meu arquivo `.travis.yml` e viram que havia um caracter oculto antes da tag `language: php`. Isso fazia o Travis-CI não detectar a linguagem e então era iniciado a build com ambiente Ruby.

Recriei o arquivo .travis.yml removendo o caracter oculto e a build funcionou perfeitamente.